# Changing parameters in .getFullYear()

Tags: javascript, html

So I want December to be 12 instead of 11 and May to be 5 instead of 4
So January starts at 1 instead of 0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Display Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Display Table 1 during December 10th through May 31st -->
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var table1Start = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 10); // December 10th
        var table1End = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 4, 31); // May 31st
        if (today >= table1Start && today <= table1End) {
            document.write("<table border='1'><tr><th>Table 1</th></tr><tr><td>This is Table 1, displayed during December 10th through May 31st.</td></tr></table>");
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Display Table 2 during the rest of the days -->
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var table1Start = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 10); // December 10th
        var table1End = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 4, 31); // May 31st
        if (today < table1Start || today > table1End) {
            document.write("<table border='1'><tr><th>Table 2</th></tr><tr><td>This is Table 2, displayed during the rest of the days.</td></tr></table>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

e
e
e
e
e
e
e
e
e
e
e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a number to another number in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603/add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the month in the 'Date' constructor starts at 0 for January. So, to get the values that you want, you need to subtract 1 from the month values for May and December, and add 1 to the month value for January. It would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Display Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Display Table 1 during December 10th through May 31st -->
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var table1Start = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 10); // December 10th
        var table1End = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, 4, 31); // May 31st of next year
        if (today.getMonth() + 1 >= 12 || today.getMonth() + 1 <= 5) {
            document.write("<table border='1'><tr><th>Table 1</th></tr><tr><td>This is Table 1, displayed during December 10th through May 31st.</td></tr></table>");
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Display Table 2 during the rest of the days -->
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var table1Start = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 10); // December 10th
        var table1End = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, 4, 31); // May 31st of next year
        if (today.getMonth() + 1 < 12 && today.getMonth() + 1 > 5) {
            document.write("<table border='1'><tr><th>Table 2</th></tr><tr><td>This is Table 2, displayed during the rest of the days.</td></tr></table>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```